# Deleted user default database - SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

I cannot connect to the database anymore, I'm getting:

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed.

**I have deleted the database during a previous session and then tried to recreate it. But the recreate failed.**

Now I am stuck with this error, what can I do?

#### Edit: I'm using Windows Authentication

Any ideas?

### Fixed:

use the command:

> sqlcmd -E -d master

then type:

> ALTER LOGIN [Your Windows Login] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=master
>
> GO

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixed it!!

use the command:

> sqlcmd -E -d master

then type:

> ALTER LOGIN [Your Windows Login] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=master
>
> GO

Answer (score 0):

You're almost certainly going to need to restore from your last backup and apply any logs.